# Linking Django with MSSQL error: The database driver doesn't support modern datatime types

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have been trying to link my mssql database to Django. I am using windows 10 on my machine. When I run the Django server there is no problem. However, when I want to use `InspectDB` I am getting this error:

```
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 365, in init_connection_state
            "The database driver doesn't support modern datatime types.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The database driver doesn't support modern datatime types.
```

My Django settings looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'my_host',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server',
            'extra_params': "Persist Security Info=False;server=my_host"
        },
    },
}
```

I don't really understand this engine idea. However, I tried other engines non of them worked. Error pops up when I run the server. With this engine not error araise when I run the server but it gives me the above mentioned error when I want to run: `python manage.py inspectdb`

any insght would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/161. Which version of pyodbc are you using and which version of Django?

Comment: django-pyodbc-azure: version 2.1 and Django 2.1

Comment: and pyodbc itself?

Comment: pyodbc: 4.0.25. I try to switch to different engine and get an error about login failed for the user

Comment: which OS?  If linux, have you already installed the sql server odbc drivers?

Comment: It's windows 10 as I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you're using mssql on linux, [you'll have to install the sql server odbc drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).  You'll have to do the same on windows clients, but that's a little more straightforward.  Once you've got the native drivers installed, update the `DRIVER` option to be `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`.

Comment: I did that and now I am getting : django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'EMEA\\kmoh'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000]
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'EMEA\\kmoh'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")

Comment: If I run simple query to get me something out of Django it works just fine. Same username. I am using windows 10 as mentioned above.

Comment: Set the `USER` and `PASSWORD` options on the settings.DATABASES dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django-pyodbc-azure 2.0, the below issue may help.

https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/142

Comment: Not really helpful I guess. I have seen it already. Thanks for the hint anyway

Answer (score 0):

A Long time ago but that can help others as nobody presented a possible solution for Windows which is the case here.

In my case, I was using ODBC DSN entries to connect to the MSSQL databases from Django like the below code and I had the ODBC System DNS entry configured for using the native and old 'SQL Server' driver wrongly, the same which is being used in the question code and what is causing the issue,  even though I had installed 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'.

```
  'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS': {  
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',

        }
    },
```

[image: ODBC Configured with old Driver]

Instead, I should configure the ODBC entry to use the new Driver

[image: ODBC Configured with new Driver]

On this thread question, it's not clear if they have installed a different driver but certainly, that drive configuration is what is causing the issue.